# Query to conditionally calculate data against previous record

Tags: mysql

Please excuse if the title is not descriptive enough.
Here is my problem scenario:

I have a table with the following columns(made up):

```
oid rev state time
1     0   S   T1
2     0   S   T2
1     0   A   T3
2     0   A   T4
2     1   MS  T5
2     1   MA  T6
2     1   M   T7
2     2   MS  T8
2     2   M   T9
```

time column is varchar (containing date/time)
I need to find the time taken for each order to transit from state to state - the valid state transitions are defined as:

```
S->A  
MS->MA  
MS-M
```

(ie., the transition can be from submit to ack, modify-submit to modify-ack or modify-submit to modified)
and MS can transition to MA and then to M, but I'm interested only in the transition from MS to MA in this case.

In the above:

```
oid 1 transitioned from S to A.  
oid 2 changed from S to A (rev 0)
oid 2 changed from MS to MA (rev 1) - here we don't want to consider transition to M
oid 2 changed from MS to M (rev 2)
```

So the query output should be as follows (timeTaken would be in millisecs):

```
oid rev timeTaken state
1    0   (T3-T1)    A
2    0   (T4-T2)    A
2    1   (T6-T5)    MA
2    2   (T9-T8)    M
```

So, if current record state is MA or M  time difference needs to be calculated only if previous record state is MS(assuming this is ordered by oid, rev, time) .  If current record state is M, skip if previous record state is MA.

Is there anyway to do this using sql query in mysql.  Any pointers will help.  Thanks.

====
The table has time as the primary key.

I have this query to get it ordered in the right way (if it helps in any way)

select oid, rev, state, time from order by orderid, time, rev

which will give:

oid rev state time
    1     0   S   T1
    1     0   A   T3
    2     0   S   T2
    2     0   A   T4
    2     1   MS  T5
    2     1   MA  T6
    2     1   M   T7
    2     2   MS  T8
    2     2   M   T9

would this help?

Comment: question, this could be much easier if your original table had some sort of auto-incrementing id. does it?

Comment: and, can we assume that the times are sorted?

Comment: I have this query to get it ordered in the right way:

Comment: sorry, newbie error (clicked enter) will update the original input area

Comment: I'm not an SQL guru, but I think what you want to do should belong to the code, not the query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I think this is something you should do in code, not with your database.

I can think of a way to do this with SQL but it's a bit convoluted. 
It goes like this. Assume your original table is `t1`.

1. create a view containing all possible transitions within each oid, rev.

   ```
   create view transitions as 
       select a.oid, a.rev, a.state as state_from, b.state as state_to, 
              a.time as time_from, b.time as time_to
       from t1 as a, t1 as b 
       where a.oid=b.oid 
         and a.rev=b.rev 
         and a.time<b.time; 


   +------+------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
   | oid  | rev  | state_from | state_to | time_from | time_to |
   +------+------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
   |    1 |    0 | S          | A        |        T1 |      T3 |
   |    2 |    0 | S          | A        |        T2 |      T4 |
   |    2 |    1 | MS         | MA       |        T5 |      T6 |
   |    2 |    1 | MS         | M        |        T5 |      T7 |
   |    2 |    1 | MA         | M        |        T6 |      T7 |
   |    2 |    2 | MS         | M        |        T8 |      T9 |
   +------+------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
   ```
2. (**Note: this step is not necessary but for educational purposes!**) Prune out everything where times are not successive. It does this by taking the row with the minimum `time_to` for each `time_from` (so it takes`T5->T6` instead of `T5->T7`)

   ```
   select a.*
   from transitions as a
   join (
        select oid, rev, time_from, min(time_to) as time_to
        from transitions
        group by time_from
        ) as b 
        on a.oid=b.oid and a.rev=b.rev 
        and a.time_from=b.time_from and a.time_to=b.time_to;

   +------+------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
   | oid  | rev  | state_from | state_to | time_from | time_to |
   +------+------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
   |    1 |    0 | S          | A        |        T1 |     T3  |
   |    2 |    0 | S          | A        |        T2 |     T4  |
   |    2 |    1 | MS         | MA       |        T5 |     T6  |
   |    2 |    1 | MA         | M        |        T6 |     T7  |
   |    2 |    2 | MS         | M        |        T8 |     T9  |
   +------+------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
   ```
3. Now you just want to select `time_from-time_to` where `state_from` and `state_to` are those transitions you are interested in. You can combine this with the previous query so that step 2. is not necessary (the only new thing from step 2. is that last and/or/or bit):

   ```
   select a.oid,a.rev,a.state_to as state,a.time_to-a.time_from as timeTaken
   from transitions as a
   join (
        select oid, rev, time_from, min(time_to) as time_to
        from transitions
        group by time_from
        ) as b 
        on a.oid=b.oid and a.rev=b.rev 
        and a.time_from=b.time_from and a.time_to=b.time_to
   and (   (a.state_from='S' and a.state_to='A')
        or (a.state_from='MS' and a.state_to='MA')
        or (a.state_from='MS' and a.state_to='M')
        );

   +------+------+-------+-----------+
   | oid  | rev  | state | timeTaken |
   +------+------+-------+-----------+
   |    1 |    0 | A     |   T3-T1   |
   |    2 |    0 | A     |   T4-T2   |
   |    2 |    2 | M     |   T6-T5   |
   |    2 |    1 | MA    |   T9-T8   |
   +------+------+-------+-----------+
   ```

So in summary, do step 1) once to create the view, and then do step 3) every time you need to perform your calculation.

I'll bet there's a more efficient way to do it -- that's not really my forte. 
I think doing the `join` is cheaper than moving it all in to the `where` clause, and creating the view is just a once-off cost.